# Stop event propagation in Meteor

Tags: events, meteor

I've hooked up some basic `click` events using Meteor's [event maps](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps).

How do I stop the event from propagating after being handled?

Meteor's docs [state](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) that

> Right now, the event handlers are wired up with jQuery, and the event
>   object you receive is a jQuery event object.

However, neither `return false` nor `e.stopPropagation()` seem to work.

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with this and this is why I switched back to jQuery events for now. I think it could be a bug but I'm not sure I didn't have time to debug. I would suggest doing the same or trying to debug.

Comment: Yea my fallback approach is to use jQuery event handlers, and then hook into meteor event maps w/ `$('#foo').trigger('bar')` from within the handlers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, stopPropagation works in a limited set of circumstances.  For propagation to stop between two handlers, the handlers must be specified on different templates, and there has to be an intervening DOM node container between the inner and outer template.  A fix is under development right now and will go into an upcoming release.

Can you post a gist of your code so I can make sure your particular case will be addresed?

As a workaround, you might try e.stopImmediatePropagation(), which is supplied by jQuery and should keep any other handlers from running.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my code, I have `<a href="#" id="show">show</a>`. I'd like to be able to handle a click event on `#show` and then prevent the href url from being followed. (Right now, `#` appears in the url bar after the click is handled.)

Comment: @dgreensp - This was mentioned in the docs as a bug, I had thought it might have been fixed as it was removed. I suggest it is added back in until this fix is in place.

Being open about bugs I think personally gives a more trustworthy environment.

Comment: Aha, you want `e.preventDefault()`!  @jonathanKingston, those bugs were fixed in 0.3.5.

Comment: "and there has to be an intervening DOM node container between the inner and outer template." - I thought this was one of the bugs, no?

Comment: I see.  The workarounds are similar.  Before, though, event handlers wouldn't get bound at all, or wouldn't get rebound, and those bugs are fixed.  There is little reason to use a wrapper DIV anymore.  I brought up a case that turned out to be hypothetical, where you have two handlers and want one to prevent bubbling to the other.  Sorry for the event issues; I'll get this sewn up!

Comment: @dgreensp Just as a followup-- yup, `preventDefault` is what I was after. Thanks! I suppose that's the canonical way to do it in vanilla jQuery as well, but I had forgotten about it after years of just using `return false`.

Comment: I actually have the problem noted in this question: two event handlers  in the same template where one is inside the other (an `icon` inside an `a`). `stopImmediatePropagation` worked, but it would be good to get this fixed as it's been over a year.

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this question while researching this myself.  The documentation for Blaze Event Maps is [here](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps).

For this problem in meteor you need to consider 2 functions depending upon what you want:

> `stopPropagation()`
>
> Prevent the event from propagating (bubbling) up to other elements. Other event handlers matching the same element are still fired, in this and other event maps.
>
> `stopImmediatePropagation()`
>
> Prevent all additional event handlers from being run on this event, including other handlers in this event map, handlers reached by bubbling, and handlers in other event maps.

What I wanted was to stop bubbling and stop propagating to other Meteor event handlers.  So `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` did the trick and it is not really a workaround as advised above.